# Regular expression with Chinese characters

Tags: regex

I tried to use regular expression to to capture both English and Chinese company name into two groups.

However I stuck at space issue, also if the line didn't contain chinese name, then i am unable to capture, can anyone help me to check what is the problem of my regular expression?

Link (https://regex101.com/r/VLwr7b/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
^([^\p{Han}]*?)(?:\s+([\p{Han}].*))?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VLwr7b/3

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this regex helps
https://regex101.com/r/VLwr7b/2

```
^([\s\S])*(.?[[:space:]])[(\[\p{Han}\/]?.+$ (new)
^([\s\S].*)[[:space:]]((?!\/)[\p{Han}\/].+)$ (old)
```

I think ultimately is due to the fact that your old regex wasn't catering to the availability of brackets hence, it was stuck.